# ESPN Fantasy Football API

Tags: api, espn

Does anyone know if it is possible to retrieve Fantasy Football information from any of the ESPN APIs? Specifically, I am looking to get the fantasy leagues, games, players, and weekly points per player from a user's ESPN fantasy football account, but haven't been able to find concrete evidence that I can.

The "Teams", "Scores & Schedules", and "Standings" APIs from ESPN appear to return the kind of data that I want, but for real NFL teams, not fantasy teams. If anyone one has tried this before and can answer either way, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case anyone else is wondering the same thing, I just got the answer through another channel. A friend of mine reached out to a contact of his at ESPN who told him that ESPN does "not currently offer public Fantasy APIs and are not actively soliciting Fantasy Football app partners at this time".

I don't know what position this contact holds at ESPN, but have to assume they are knowledgeable.

Answer (score 3):

I created a project [Fantasy-Football-IO](https://github.com/vbudhram/fantasy-football-io), that scrapes ESPN and Yahoo Fantasy Football sites for this data. It also provides a portal to view all your ESPN/Yahoo teams, standings, players and stats.

Comment: Hi Vijay, do you have an example of how I might use Fantasy-Football-IO on my site to pull live data from ESPN? I didn't see any instructions in your repository. Thanks, I love the idea!

Comment: Hey Parguian, glad you like the idea! It was a real pain to have to manage many leagues from different accounts. Currently, the server is only meant to run locally and parsing functionality also needs to be updated for 2015. Good luck this year!

Answer (score 2):

ESPN currently do not provide open API for this.But you can also try yahoo YQL (https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) for getting data.

Answer (score 1):

ESPN now has a private API for it. It supports both public leagues and private leagues (though, I believe authentication has to be done on their normal sign-in page).

It is not documented but a good starting point for looking into it would be [this GitHub project](https://github.com/rbarton65/espnff).